# Block is not calling properly in magento 2 custom module

Tags: magento2, custom-block, custom-template

I have a custom theme in magento 2 website.

In home page i called a banner slider(Banner_slider is a custom module)

I called the slider like this in home_content.phtml(**design/frontend/company/projectname/Magento_theme/templates/home-content.phtml**) like this

```
<?php include ($block->getTemplateFile('Company_Bannermanager::bannermanager.phtml')) ?>
```

location of bannermanager.phtml is - (**app\code\Company\Bannermanager\view\frontend\templates**)

In this file i called the block method(**getHomepageBanners()**) like this

```
<?php $home_banners =  $block->getHomepageBanners(); ?>
```

Block file location is -( **app\code\Company\Bannermanager\Block\Index** )

I am getting this error

> Error filtering template: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in D:\xampp\htdocs\mollys_spirits\app\code\Company\Bannermanager\view\frontend\templates\bannermanager.phtml on line 17

I know i can call this block like below

```
<?php 
$blockObj= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Company\Bannermanager\Block\Index\Index');
$home_banners =  $blockObj->getHomepageBanners(); ?>
```

What part i am missing in first method.

**Update**

My layout file is homebanner_index_index.xml-(**app\code\Eight25media\Bannermanager\view\frontend\layout**)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <title>Banners</title>
</head> 
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Company\Bannermanager\Block\Index\Index" name="homebanner"  template="Company_Bannermanager::bannermanager.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Comment: Where do you use `homebanner_index_index.xml` ? Is there a custom controller?

Comment: i am not referring anywhere in my index controller.theme page is in the  theme folder

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your way doesn't follow the best practice. Try to add it via XML layout and call it by using `$block->getChildHtml('your.block.alias');`.

One more thing about your error. This is because the block class -`Company\Bannermanager\Block\Index\Index` didn't initialize. So, you couldn't get its function.

**[EDIT]**

In your case, you can simply add your xml to home page via Admin. Open your Cms home page. Add your xml layout via `Layout Update XML` section.

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Company\Bannermanager\Block\Index\Index" name="homebanner"  template="Company_Bannermanager::bannermanager.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

Or add directly to content:

```
{{ block class="Company\Bannermanager\Block\Index\Index"  template="Company_Bannermanager::bannermanager.phtml" }}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.I have my layout file also.i will update the question

Comment: @Mujahidh Okay! Update your question with the new errors also.

Comment: @ Khoa TruongDinh previously also the layout file is there